# Не выводится сообщение об ошибке валидации на safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validation

Имеется проблема. Использую валидацию, плагин validate.js. На safari, при клике валидация "физически" срабатывает, но нет текста ошибки. На иных браузерах все работает норм. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reg_form").validate({
    rules: {
      phone: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      phone: "Пожалуйста, введите номер Вашего телефона"
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form class="reg_form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="name" value="">
  <input type="tel" pattern="(\+?\d[- .\(\)]*){5,15}" placeholder="Телефон*" name="phone" required="" value="">
  <button type="submit" value="" ">Отправить</button>
</form>
```